# GCP - Terraform - google_project_services module breaks terraform pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, module, terraform, pipeline

As per subject title, when using this module to just delete the default network and nothing else, this module breaks my terraform entirely, even when the module is removed/commented out, I get the same error still:

```
resource "google_project_service" "service" {
  project = var.project_id
  service = "compute.googleapis.com"
  disable_dependent_services = false
  disable_on_destroy = false

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "gcloud -q compute networks delete default --project=${var.project_id}"
  }
}
```

This is the error I get (replaced my actual project id with "project_id"):

```
Error: Error when reading or editing Project Service project_id/compute.googleapis.com: Error disabling service "compute.googleapis.com" for project "project_id": googleapi: Error 400: The service compute.googleapis.com is depended on by the following active service(s): container.googleapis.com; Please specify disable_dependent_services=true if you want to proceed with disabling all services.
│ Help Token: Ae-hA1POavq8x9V18i7Um0cW3sx_9lXuuNzjqDzX3zZ3HEYjJ91bGelEobL22DVMdY27NCRrCtZbyE-GbagPtdmxWhdpSamwl0JJomQ4KTRUQDK5
│ Details:
│ [
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.PreconditionFailure",
│     "violations": [
│       {
│         "subject": "?error_code=100001\u0026service_name=compute.googleapis.com\u0026services=container.googleapis.com",
│         "type": "googleapis.com"
│       }
│     ]
│   },
│   {
│     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
│     "domain": "serviceusage.googleapis.com",
│     "metadata": {
│       "service_name": "compute.googleapis.com",
│       "services": "container.googleapis.com"
│     },
│     "reason": "COMMON_SU_SERVICE_HAS_DEPENDENT_SERVICES"
│   }
```

│ ]
│ , failedPrecondition

Have had issues like this before with this module when wanting to enable gcp apis in a newly created project with terraform so just stopped using it.

Any ideas how I fix the above?

I am doing a terraform init, refresh, plan and apply, this fails and gets the error above on the terraform apply stage.

Comment: seems, the module/resource was still defined in the state file, removing that fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems the module/resource was still defined in the state file, removing that fixed it

Comment: Did you remove it from the state file  with `terraform state rm module.project-services`  ?

Comment: No, I just downloaded the state file, removed it manually then reuploaded the state file to my bucket

Answer (score 0):

Since some other service using `compute.googleapis.com` as a dependent  service. so its stopping `compute.googleapis.com` from disabling because it might affect those dependent service. Here is the Reference [**Doc1**](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/serviceusage/latest/google.cloud.service_usage_v1.types.DisableServiceRequest)
Try like this it should work

```
 disable_dependent_services = True
```

Comment: Thanks but that's the problem, I don't want to disable any of the google apis. Also, even when the module/resource is removed from my terraform main.tf, it still errors on this i.e. as if the module/resource were still in my main.tf.... which I don't get.